# child views of window doesnot resizes using autolayout feature

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have a textfield created using xib over my window.I have enabled autolayout property for my window.I want my textfield to grow horizontally to meet the window bounds.My window grows but not the textfield. Please help!I am using Mac OS Lion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read my answer on your other question?  Select the text field in Interface Builder.  A blue line connecting the field to the right side of the window represents a constraint that will cause the right side of the field to stay a fixed distance from the edge of the window.  If you drag the text field so that it clicks into place (the human interface guidelines defined distance away from the edge of the window), then that will create the constraint.  If not, you can do it by hand from the menus: Editor > Pin > Trailing Space to Superview.

You might find the documentation helpful, since it has images and explanation and such.  There's a bunch!  [Interface Builder](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/_index.html), [programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html), [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/Cocoa_Autolayout_Demos/Introduction/Intro.html), [release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/UserExperience/RNAutomaticLayout/_index.html), [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.8270634034.08270634040.8367260891?i=2124831445).

Comment: Ken i want my view to expand fill the entire window.constarints are fine.I had gone through the documentation u r mentioning